# Turn off visiting behaviour when navigating to file in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I go to another file, using F12 on a type name in the code, it will open the file in a read-tab to the right. If I navigate further the new file will replace the previous one.

In Visual Studio 2010 it would open a new tab for each file I go to. I've tried to get used to the new behaviour, but I can't stand it.

How do I turn this feature off?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 has a new **Tabs and Windows** settings page under Tools > Options > Environment that controls this kind of behavior:

[image: Tools - Options - Tabs and Windows]

You probably want to disable **Allow new files to be opened in the preview tab** in the **Preview Tab** section.

Comment: If I [just wanted to turn off preview for PDF files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13044498/575530), how would I do that?