# How do I turn off preview in Visual Studio 2012 for pdf files?

Tags: editor, visual-studio-2012, preview

When I select a file in solution explorer it opens immediately in a preview tab.

[image: PDF Preview in Visual Studio 2012]

For many file types this is a useful feature. But when adding PDFs to a website it is not. How do I tune Visual Studio 2012's preview feature so that it does not preview PDF files?

(N.B. [Kyralessa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5486/kyralessa) shows how to turn the preview feature off in an [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12392339/575530), but I'd like to leave it on generally, and turn it off for PDFs.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the pdf file while holding ALT key - the file will be selected in solution explorer but it will not be open in preview tab.

Comment: Thanks [Jarek](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1515181/jarek-kardas). Does that mean there is no way to turn off previewing for specific file extensions like PDF?